# How to get libraries folder list in Windows for current user?

Tags: c++, windows

In Windows environment there is "Libraries" root which contains "Documents", "Pictures" or even "My Own Library".

Further, "Documents" will refer to few locations - "My Documents", "Public Documents", "Something Else"

At the end it's pretty clear how to find out where "My Documents" or "Public Documents" are sitting on the disk.

I wonder how can I get, in C++, list of those libraries names, and then how to get all library locations list (I can see this list thru "Properties->Library Locations")

Comment: Libraries is a virtual folder, not a real one. Well, sort of anyway.  It doesn't contain the folders you're seeing, there is a layer of abstraction.  You might have some luck examining the contents of C:\Users\<you>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries, which is the folder that controls the library's contents.

Comment: The [Shell Libraries Command Line sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd940379) shows how to access libraries programmatically.

Comment: @RaymondChen The download links on shell libraries page are not working. That page on msdn needs an update. Do you have links to the shell sample code gallery?

Comment: This GitHub is very useful: https://github.com/pauldotknopf/WindowsSDK7-Samples

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but you can get the Library folder path by calling [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with parameter `FOLDERID_Libraries` and enumerate from there.